# How to check drop-down values using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have drop-down and Textbox inside a Gridview so I want to check the followings on a button click:
(1) Check if NOTHING is selected from the drop down first (the drop-down options are either YES, NO or NA) .  If nothing is selected, I want to show message that reads like this “Please make selection from the drop-down”
(2) If the selection from the drop-down is NO  and the Textbox is blank or empty then I want to show message that says: “Please provide comments”

The first code checks if the text-box is blank and it works and the 2nd code checks if no selection is made from the drop down and that one works fine too so how can i combine between those 2 codes?  I want to execute both codes on button click, right now it is only calling the first code.  please help.  Thanks.
here is my code that checks if the textbox is blank:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
    function Validate() {
        var flag = false;
        var gridView = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');

        for (var i = 1; i < gridView.rows.length; i++) {
            var selects = gridView.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('select');
            var areas = gridView.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('textarea');
            if (selects != null && areas != null) {
                if (areas[0].type == "textarea") {
                    var txtval = areas[0].value;
                    var selectval = selects[0].value;
                    if (selectval == "No" && (txtval == "" || txtval == null)) {

                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        flag = true;
                        document.getElementById('<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>').style.visibility = 'visible';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!flag) {
            alert('Please note that comments are required if you select "No" from the dropdown box.  Thanks');
            document.getElementById('<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        return flag;
    }
</script>
```

and here is the code that checks the drop-down

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function validate_DD() {
          var flag = true;
          var dropdowns = new Array(); //Create array to hold all the dropdown lists.
          var gridview = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>'); //GridView1 is the id of ur gridview.
          dropdowns = gridview.getElementsByTagName('Select'); //Get all dropdown lists contained in GridView1.
          for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
              if (dropdowns.item(i).value == 'Select') //If dropdown has no selected value
              {
                  flag = false;
                  break; //break the loop as there is no need to check further.
              }
          }
          if (!flag) {
              alert('Please select either Yes, No or NA in each dropdown and click the Save button again.  Thanks');
              document.getElementById('<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>').style.visibility = 'hidden';

          }

          return flag;

      }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select id="ddlCars">
  <option value="1">Honda</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">Toyota</option>
  <option value="3">BMW</option>
</select>
```

Accessing dropdown:

```
To get the value:
var el = document.getElementById("ddlCars");
var val = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value; // val will be 2

To get the text:
var el = document.getElementById("ddlCars");
var car = el.options[el.selectedIndex].text; //car will be Toyota
```

Comment: this did not help, i have my dropdonw and textbox inside the gridview.

Comment: Can you debug in browser to see if areas has any textareas in it? Otherwise, I would comment textarea and try to see I can read value of the dropdown in a particular row in the grdid

Comment: Okay, i just updated my question.  I have posted 2 js codes, the first one checks the texbox if it is blank, and the 2nd one checks the drop-down and both work fine.  So my question is how can i combine both?  so once the button is clicked then it executes both codes. thanks.

Comment: any help here please?

Comment: I would alert the dropdowns.length to see if the array has anything in it. If yes, then alert JSON.Stringify to print out what is in each dropdown. Is there any place where I can test and play with your code? You can also test your pieces in here http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: If you drop the HTML source of the grid in jsfiddle site, I can look at  it further. Only list 2 rows...